# Github. Изменено имя у репозитория на Github

Tags: github

Поменял имя у репозитория в самом гите(то бишь, поменял имя у удаленного репозитория).
Теперь же, что бы я не делал, `git push` отказывается работать.
url через remote поменял, всё до одного места.

Comment: Не пробовали клонировать себе на компьютер репозиторий?

Comment: Как это сделать?
Я просто туплю, гитом только начал пользоваться.

Comment: Вы что используете в качестве git? (какую программу)

Comment: либо он у вас в текстовый редактор\IDE встроен?

Comment: Если правильно понял Вас, через git bash

Comment: Значит консолька, тогда git clone адрес вашего репозитория (на github, gitlab либо bitbucket

Comment: Просто клонировать  удаленный репоз. к себе и оперировать с ним?
А что еще удобно помимо консольки?

Comment: А если не хотите мучиться с командами, используйте какой-нибудь git с GUI, например SourceTree

Comment: да, клонируйте к себе и работайте уже с ним

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь.)

Comment: ну а если вы все же захотите изучить git в полной мере, пройдите курсы на https://learngitbranching.js.org/

Comment: Это очень полезный ресурс, благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего, на мой взгляд, в папке проекта открыть файл `.git/config` и переименовать remote соответствующим образом.

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = URL_TO_REPO_HERE
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

То же самое можно сделать командой:

```
git remote set-url origin <url>
```

где `<url>` для github, может быть:

- `https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git`
- `git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git`

Потом следует выполнить `git fetch`, чтобы убедиться, что всё работает.

Comment: кмк проще `git remote set-url origin <url>`

Comment: Это нужно запомнить, а файл он вот он, всегда тут.

Comment: Таки добавлю в ответ, если вы не против

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую установить программу для работы с гит, и склонировать к себе репозиторий - https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/download/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]