# Как поменять имя пользователя и пароль при коммите на github в git

Tags: git, github

У меня был старый аккаунт на github, сейчас завел новый аккаунт и соответсвенно репозитарий при попытке сделать
git push

git выдает
remote: Permission to UserName/rsschool-cv.git denied to User1.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/UserName/rsschool-cv.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Как принудительно заставить git работать не под User1 а под новым юзером и паролем. Спасибо.

Comment: Пробовал как сказано здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/824608/github-%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d1%83-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-github   то бишь git remote set-url origin <url> не помогает.

Comment: так может надо просто добавить новый удаленный репозиторий?

Comment: почему же я сначала клонировал новый репозитарий в новую папку git clone, но он все равно лезет в новый репозитарий но под старым пользователем

Comment: если винда, то в винде надо удалить пользователя для github. Панель управления\Учетные записи пользователей\Диспетчер учетных данных

Comment: Спасибо большое помогло.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сменить или удалить пользователя в git bash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585421/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2-git-bash)